# Compute value of next row as a function of previous rows with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to implement the following algorithm for my DataFrame:

```
if Tenure==0: 
   s=1 
else: 
   s = (previous value from "s") * (1-previous value from "h")
```

The column `s` is computed as a function of `h`, with an initial value of 1.

Input DataFrame:

```
        popt    stopt    popcum    h        s
Tenure                  
 0.0    2383    508.0   5067890 0.000100    1
 1.0    18358   17310.0 5065507 0.003417    0
 2.0    16742   15103.0 5047149 0.002992    0
 3.0    13298   11361.0 5030407 0.002258    0
 4.0    9566    9522.0  5017109 0.001898    0


result3["s"]=result3.apply(funkcyjka)
```

To skip first condition i just edited first row becouse its the only one with Tenure = 0

Here's what I've come up with:

```
def funkcyjka(res):
    x=0
    lol=(res["s"].iloc[x])*(1-(res["h"].iloc[x]))
    x+=1
    return lol
```

But it does not do what I expect. How can i implement this function to my Dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you trace this out on paper, this is what is actually computed for each row of `s`:

```
1
1 * (1 - h0)
(1 - h0) * (1 - h1)
(1 - h0) * (1 - h1) * (1 - h2)
...
```

So, you'll need `shift` + `cumprod` here:

```
df['s'] = (1 - df['h'].shift()).fillna(1).cumprod()
df
         popt    stopt   popcum         h         s
Tenure                                             
0.0      2383    508.0  5067890  0.000100  1.000000
1.0     18358  17310.0  5065507  0.003417  0.999900
2.0     16742  15103.0  5047149  0.002992  0.996483
3.0     13298  11361.0  5030407  0.002258  0.993502
4.0      9566   9522.0  5017109  0.001898  0.991259
```

Comment: Its working! thank you! <3 I'm trying to convert whole chapter from "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel"...  i think i will have maany more questions :D